# how to save canvas image and share to facebook using fb.api

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html2canvas

i want to save canvas image to folder and share that in facebook on wall of the user logged i'm using html2canvas plugin but my issue is the  div element is not getting drawn in the canvas the data in the div is coming from database following is the code i have written.

HtmlCode:

```
<div class="fan_wrap">
         <ul class="fan_list">
                <% foreach (ProfileDetails currentFollowers in AllFollowers)
                  {
                  %>
  <li <%if (currentFollowers.ID != 0) { Response.Write("class=\"locate\""); } %>>
  <img src="<%=currentFollowers.ProfileImg %>" alt="<%=currentFollowers.Name %>" title="<%=currentFollowers.Name %>" />
   <div class="frame"></div>
     </li>
     <%} %>
   </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="logo_water_mark">
    <img src="images/trans_logo.png" alt="" />
     </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#share_lnk').on('click',function () {
            html2canvas($('.fan_wrap'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                   var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    image = image.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'FacebookLogin.aspx/UploadImage',
                        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert('Image saved successfully !');
                        }
                    });
                    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
                    newImg.src = url;
                    document.body.appendChild(newImg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you have to save the canvas image on the domain from where you want to share it as your facebook app supports only one. next you can share the url of the pic to be sharer like below:

```
FB.ui({
                                method: 'feed',
                                name: "some name",
                                link: "somelink.com",
                                picture: urltobeshared,
                                caption: 'some caption',
                                description: "some descrtiption",
                              },
                              function(response) {
                                if (response && response.post_id) {
                                  console.log('Thank you');
                                }                  
                              }
                        );
                    },
```

docs are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart).Hope that helps

Comment: ok thnk you and how can i draw images to canvas the images path are from facebook graph url

Comment: I am not sure what your question is but if you are asking how to draw images on canvas then it is very easy.check this (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_img) example of w3schools and you will understand.Moreover while drawing on the canvas you don't need to be concerned about the origin of the images you are drawing if that is what you were concerned about.hope it helps

Comment: yes the example only works if your image contain in same local server if i want to write external image url i am not able do that

Comment: 'SomeimageObj.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';' try this for the image which you draw in the canvas.Hope it helps.